# Angular ng-repeat to access object with in an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, object-object-mapping

Framework: AngularJS 1.4.X
Problem: Accessing Object with in Object
In Built directive: ng-repeat

**In Directive:**

```
for ( i=0; i< something.lenght < i++)
    if ( element in elements ){
        sendData[i]=
        {
           pair:element,
           row:i
        } 
    } 
}
scope.obj[sendData] = sendData;
```

**In View:**

```
<somedirective obj="obj">
    <md-content ng-repeat="data in obj">
         {{obj[data].pair}}  or {{data.pair}}
    </md-content>
</somedirective>
```

**Console Log** ( `JSON.stringify(scope.obj)` )**:**

```
{"[object Object]":{"14":{"pair":"HIT|CEDR3","row":14},"15":{"pair":"HIT|CEPR3","row":15},"16":{"pair":"HIT|CEKR3","row":16},"24":{"pair":"Book|Pro0","row":24}}
```

**{{data}}:**

```
{"14":{"pair":"HIT|CEDR3","row":14},"15":{"pair":"HIT|CEPR3","row":15},"16":{"pair":"HIT|CEKR3","row":16},"24":{"pair":"Book|Pro0","row":24}}
```

I'm not able to access `pair` property from the second object in ng-repeat, as i mentioned in the view section i have used  `{{obj[data].pair}}  or {{data.pair}}` and if i use `{{data}}` it will print all object property/data list.

Comment: How are you unable to access the `pair` property by using `{{data.pair}}`? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do here. Could you clarify?

Comment: As I know the ng repeat iterate over array not objects

Comment: @BenBeck: yes, i'm not able to with `{{data.pair}}`. I don't know what am i missing here.

Comment: There is no `data.pair` in your sample.  there is a `data.14.pair`, a `data.15.pair`, etc..  On top of that, `ng-repeat` isn't designed to iterate over object properties.

Comment: @Mad-D, I created a really simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9oL94pcj/262/) and it seems I am able to iterate through the `pair` objects. Unless this isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: @BenBeck that works, but his data is structured slightly differently than your simple fiddle.  his output is `{{data}}`, not `{{obj}}`;  it appears that his `obj` has multiple `data` with multiple `pair` each.

Comment: @Claies -- Ah my mistake, you are certainly right. Might be easiest to re-structure how the data is coming into the AngularJS application.

Comment: @Claies: what would be the alternative way to build the object dynamically ?

Comment: make `obj` an array, and use `push`

Comment: No luck, so i declared `scope.obj = [ ]` and at last `scope.obj.push(sendData);`

Comment: Try scope.obj = sendData;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scope.obj = {};
for ( i=0; i< something.lenght < i++)
    if ( element in elements ){
        sendData[i]=
        {
           pair:element,
           row:i
        } 
    } 
}
scope.obj = sendData;
```

I hope this will help others, and thank you Oskar.